# Angular 8: Add Div dynamically

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular8

Here is my **HTML** code below.

```
<div class="row" style="padding-bottom: 5%;">

          <div class="col-md-12" id="HolidayDiv">
            <div class="form-group row justify-content-md-center m-b-10">
              <label class="col-md-4 text-md-right col-form-label">
                <div>HOLIDAY NAME</div>
                <div><input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="" class="form-control"></div>
              </label>

              <label class="col-md-4 text-md-right col-form-label">
                <div>HOLIDAY DATE</div>
                <div>
                  <div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control">
                    <div class="input-group-addon">
                      <span class="far fa-calendar-alt"></span>
                    </div>
                    <i class="fas fa-lg fa-fw m-r-10 m-l-5 m-t-10 text-grey fa-indent"></i>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- end #content -->
          <!-- end col-10 -->
        </div>
```

Here is screenshot below.
[image: div desc]
Here the **small red box** is an **add button** and the **large red box** div is what i need to add below dynamically.

Here is my **typescript** file below.

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'CustomerProfileAdd',
  templateUrl: './CustomerProfileAdd.html',
  styleUrls: ['./CustomerProfileAdd.css']
})

export class CustomerProfileAdd {
  active = 1;  
}
```

As i have several examples but only as https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pujraw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css and as like https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamically-add-rows-gk4veg?file=app%2Fapp.component.html but for division I couldn't find it.

Comment: You have to use `ngFor` and and and array to do this. When you do `array.push`, Angular will ad another element to that list

Answer (score 0):

Use Reactive form. it has powerful features for all kind of form operations.First get an idea about reactive forms from [here](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms). use **FormBuilder** for build the dynamic array and  call this method on your button click

```
addRowsToTable(): void {
    this.sampleTableForm = this.FormBuilder.group({ you can pass your row defintion : 
    yourRow[] });
    let index: number = 1;
    const row: FormGroup = this.fBuilder.group({
        reactiveFormField1: [null, Validators.required],
        reactiveFormField2: [null, Validators.required],
        .....
    });

    this.yourrow.push(row);
    index++;
}
```